# What is the intuitive meaning of outer product in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

What is the intuitive meaning of outer product of $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi |$ in Hilbert space?

Answer (score 2):

It is the projection operator of some state $|\phi\!\!>$ onto $|\psi\!\!>$.

For example, if $|\psi\!\!>$ is a state of some definite momentum $p$, and $|\phi\!\!>$ some state of uncertain momentum and position, then 
$|\psi\!\!><\!\!\psi| \phi\!\!>$ selects the momentum = $p$ component of $|\phi\!\!>$.

Comment: Usually `\langle` and `\rangle` are preferred over `<` and `<` as delimiters $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about those because they are not in the original LaTeX book I have. But this at least gave me the chance to use \! a few times!

Comment: Have you seen this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) before? I find it very helpful.